# How to search for links to a particular external site?

Tags: discussion, search, hyperlinks, spam

#### Setup:

Cooler heads and wiser minds than mine, please consider.

I came across a Question that struck me as chatty and not suitable for StackExchange, much less Math.SE.  The initial response was simply to vote-to-close, but I noticed that the Question seemed centered on a link to an external site that had materials that were relevant, and in fact made it difficult to see what Real Question might have been in the OP's thinking.

Subsequently I looked at other Questions posed by the same User, quickly finding a half-dozen that were a similar pattern:  rather shallow, even vague problems that mention a page with related material at the same external site.

The dirty part of my mind thinks this could be a ploy to steer traffic to that ad-supported site.  No relationship between the User (who is fairly recent here, and Unregistered) and the external site is specifically disclosed in the posts I saw. The User's account here indicates 13 years of age.

If it were a clearly commercial promotion, I'd have no qualms about flagging it as spam.  Note the [advice in this Meta.SE post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/91697/what-is-the-policy-for-non-commercial-affiliate-links-on-the-stack-exchange-netw) suggests avoiding even the appearance of self-interested links.

#### Here's my Question:

Is there a way to search Math.SE for links to this external site by other "users"?  I'm imagining Google Analytics or something similar allows for such a search.  Searching for the site's domain name turns up three or four unrelated posts, which only suggests that it's a site that's been around awhile and has some legitimate fans.  Searching for the embedded URL links would tell me whether Math.SE is being gamed with a series of accounts/posts to drive traffic from here to there.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use the `url:` parameter of site search. For example, [this search](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=url%3Aams.org) finds all posts with links to `ams.org` domain.

---

You can also use Data Explorer to search raw sources of posts for hyperlinks of particular kind (or for any string of characters). Here's a [query](http://data.stackexchange.com/math/query/243354/search-all-posts-for-a-string-of-characters?text=ams.org).

Comment: That worked, although at first I was doing it wrong, and then it turned out all the posts that I'd grown suspicious over were made *after* the last SE data dump on Nov. 2nd.  Anyway, it appears that the posts are not part of a long-standing pattern.

Comment: Turns out I was reinventing a square wheel: site search has `url:` parameter. Useful for locating spam of known type.

Comment: [Similar query](http://data.stackexchange.com/math/query/256389/search-all-comments-for-a-string-of-characters?text=mathoverflow) for searching in comments. I guess it can be occasionally useful, too.