# Policy on hyperlink shortening/redirection sites

Tags: discussion, policy, hyperlinks, best-practices

While reviewing a LQ post, I found the answer contained a link, purportedly to a video providing a proof requested in the respective question.  However the link was presented as a bit.ly "shortened" link.

This has the effect of disguising the real URL's format, and potentially contributes to link-rot, so as a general preference I'd like to see this avoided.  Using my new-found [hyperlink hyper-vision](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17240/how-to-search-for-links-to-a-particular-external-site), I see there are currently 52 posts containing URL "bit.ly" on Main Math.SE (none on Meta), of which 29 are in Answers. (I'll make a CW post to summarize instances of other common link-shorteners.)

While there are legitimate reasons for shortening and branding links, I find it difficult to imagine those purposes applying here (Math.SE or even StackExchange communities generally).  However my ignorance is not a wonderful justification for an editing campaign to remove and replace where possible.

A discussion or pointers to previous discussion on this point of policy would be appreciated.

Comment: I had sometimes problems with links to WA (as described [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/4482/carets-stop-hyperlinks-working) and [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/8656/trouble-in-quoting-a-page-from-wolfram-alpha) and maybe some other posts.) I usually solve this by using tinyurl. (Although probably urlencoding should work too.)

Comment: Nice insight.  I'm going to take a look at SO and MetaSE for a wider perspective.

Comment: The proposal [Ban URL shortening services](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64450/ban-url-shortening-services) has (status-declined), in the sense that SE will not automatically stop these from being posted. However, users should feel free to edit to un-obscure problematic short links, or flag comments containing them.

Comment: This now-closed [thread on MetaSE](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/99136/let-me-flag-that-for-you-url-shortener-cleanup) could be something of a model.  As Martin's Comment amply illustrates, redirected links can serve a good purpose, and editing things on a case-by-case basis (rather than imposing a systematic ban) makes sense.  It also makes sense to have guidelines formalized here as reference.

Comment: @Martin: The hyperlink button on the editing toolbar automatically fixes those links, as mentioned in some of the answers on the posts you linked to.

Comment: In the link posted by hardmath [this answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/99136/let-me-flag-that-for-you-url-shortener-cleanup/99137#99137) points out that there are some cages where direct links cause problems and URL shorteners can help. One example is links to [Wayback Machine](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/99136/let-me-flag-that-for-you-url-shortener-cleanup/99137#comment251095_99137). If I try linking to ...

Comment: ... a [specific version](http://web.archive.org/web/20141202074301/http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/17504/policy-on-hyperlink-shortening-redirection-sites) of a page it works ok. Also [listing all captures](http://web.archive.org/web/20141202074301*/http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/17504/policy-on-hyperlink-shortening-redirection-sites), it seems to work. So maybe the situation has improved in the meantime.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A comment above from Famous Blue Raincoat is probably the best answer to this question:

> The proposal [Ban URL shortening services](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64450/ban-url-shortening-services) has (status-declined), in the sense that SE will not automatically stop these from being posted. However, users should feel free to edit to un-obscure problematic short links, or flag comments containing them. –  Famous Blue Raincoat Dec 1 '14 at 14:08

Various cases where shortened links may serve a useful purpose are noted in some other Comments above.

Comment: Thanks, Carl.  Famous Blue Raincoat -- if that's his *real* name -- also deserves credit for spotting the search tool identified in this [related Answer](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/17241/3111).